# Issue with Azure Logic APP EPOCH DATE Conversion

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, epoch

I have an issue with epoch date conversion in Azure logic app.
I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I have divided my logic app in different steps to first get the Timestamp and remove "/Date" and the trailing "/".

And then I use the add to time function where i am getting an unexpected result.

Input:

```
"EndDate": "/Date(253402214400000)/",
"StartDate": "/Date(946684800000)/"
```

Expected output

```
 "EndDate"  : "2000-01-01T00:00:00",
 "StartDate": "9999-12-31T00:00:00"
```

Current result:

```
"EndDate": "1942-11-15T20:26:40.0000000Z",
"StartDate": "2026-10-14T16:21:20.0000000Z"
```

Logic app code

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": {
                    "root": {
                        "CostAccountID": "AD100",
                        "EndDate": "9999-12-31T00:00:00Z",
                        "StartDate": "2000-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "root": {
                        "CostAccountID": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['root']?['CostAccountID']}",
                        "EndDate1": "@{int(replace(replace(body('Parse_JSON')?['root']?['EndDate'],'/Date(',''),')/',''))}",
                        "StartDate1": "@{int(replace(replace(body('Parse_JSON')?['root']?['StartDate'],'/Date(',''),')/',''))}"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_3": {
                "inputs": {
                    "root": {
                        "CostAccountID": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['root']?['CostAccountID']}",
                        "EndDate": "@{addToTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', int(body('Parse_JSON_2')?['root']?['EndDate1']), 'Second')}",
                        "StartDate": "@{addToTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', int(body('Parse_JSON_2')?['root']?['StartDate1']), 'Second')}"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Compose')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "root": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "CostAccountID": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "EndDate": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "StartDate": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Parse_JSON_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Compose_2')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "root": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "CostAccountID": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "EndDate1": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "StartDate1": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Response": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@outputs('Compose_2')",
                    "statusCode": 200
                },
                "kind": "http",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose_3": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Response"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

Comment: I've taken your JSON definition but am getting this when I run it ... `Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose_2' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type.'.` at the `Compose2` step.

Answer (score 2):

After reproducing from my end, we have observed that you have used the value in milliseconds. Try converting it into seconds and follow the same approach. Below is the code I'm using -

```
{
  "root": {
    "CostAccountID": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['root']?['CostAccountID']}",
    "EndDate": "@{addSeconds('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', div(int(body('Parse_JSON_2')?['root']?['EndDate1']),1000))}",
    "StartDate": "@{addSeconds('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', div(int(body('Parse_JSON_2')?['root']?['StartDate1']),1000))}"
  }
}
```

***RESULTS:***

[image]

I have made changes to your code view. Below is the updated one

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": {
                    "root": {
                        "CostAccountID": "AD100",
                        "EndDate": "/Date(253402214400000)/",
                        "StartDate": "/Date(946684800000)/"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "root": {
                        "CostAccountID": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['root']?['CostAccountID']}",
                        "EndDate1": "@{int(replace(replace(body('Parse_JSON')?['root']?['EndDate'],'/Date(',''),')/',''))}",
                        "StartDate1": "@{int(replace(replace(body('Parse_JSON')?['root']?['StartDate'],'/Date(',''),')/',''))}"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_3": {
                "inputs": {
                    "root": {
                        "CostAccountID": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['root']?['CostAccountID']}",
                        "EndDate": "@{addSeconds('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', div(int(body('Parse_JSON_2')?['root']?['EndDate1']),1000))}",
                        "StartDate": "@{addSeconds('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', div(int(body('Parse_JSON_2')?['root']?['StartDate1']),1000))}"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Compose')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "root": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "CostAccountID": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "EndDate": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "StartDate": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Parse_JSON_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Compose_2')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "root": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "CostAccountID": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "EndDate1": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "StartDate1": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Response": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@outputs('Compose_3')",
                    "statusCode": 200
                },
                "kind": "http",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose_3": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Response"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```